# Error related to AWS Sqs Queue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-sqs

I get this error in laravel when trying to access Queue -

```
Class 'Aws\Sqs\SqsClient' not found
```

My default queue is 'sync' and I have not required 'Sqs' anywhere in my composer.json. Then why is this happening? Is it compulsory to include it in newer versions of Laravel.

Comment: do you have any environment setup?

Comment: @itachi What did you mean? I didn't get you.

Comment: check [**environment**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this package: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

This package AWS components with works!

I recommend it to you

Answer (score 18):

First check value  QUEUE_DRIVER in your .env file. 
In your case it must be equal to „sync“

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Than check your supervisor configuration file. Probably you forget to change this line:

```
command=php /my/app/dir/artisan queue:work **sqs** ...
```

to

```
command=php /my/app/dir/artisan queue:work **sync** ...
```

as it described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: is it possible even though this error is coming, other jobs are working fine

Answer (score 3):

unmet dependency so you need to do this

`composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`

Answer (score 1):

I had this config in the env file `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` so in my case I had to run the command without **sync** or **sqs**

```
command=php /my/app/dir/artisan queue:work ...
```